# WordPress - Query from the posts, postmeta and usermeta

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called ‘bo_codes’ with several options in postmeta for each post. One of the options in postmeta is called ‘claimed_by’ and is a user ID from the users table. On the front-end I’m using ‘get_the_author_meta( 'first_name', $claimed_by ).' '.get_the_author_meta( 'last_name', $claimed_by );’ to get the users first and last name. This is all working correctly and the data is coming into a WP_List_Table. I’m using the WP_List_Table search box and would like the user to be able to search for the users first and last name.  When a user does a search I am using WP_Query to get the results. This works fine for getting the postmeta but I need to be able to search the usermeta for the user first and last name and show the appropriate ‘bo_codes’.

Here’s the query I have so far.

```
$searchvalue = $_REQUEST['s'];
        $args = array(
            'post_type'             => 'bo_codes',
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'        => '-1',                
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND', //**** Use AND or OR as per your required Where Clause 
                array(
                'relation' => 'OR',             
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'bo_code',
                        'value'   => $searchvalue,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'run_number',
                        'value'   => $searchvalue,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'claimed_by',
                        'value'   => $searchvalue,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'status',
                    'value'   => 'Claimed',
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            ),  

        );

$result = new WP_Query($args);
    $data = array_map(
        function( $post ) {
            return (array) $post;
        },
        $result->posts
    );
```

Should I be using ‘post_join’ action or bypass WP_Query and use ‘$wpdb->get_results’ with a special query that using ‘LEFT JOIN’?

Here’s what I tried using a get_results.

```
global $wpdb;
    $query = "  
        SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID,
        first_name.meta_value AS first_name,
        last_name.meta_value AS last_name
       FROM $wpdb->posts

  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta  AS first_name 
         ON $wpdb->posts.ID = first_name.post_id AND first_name.meta_key='first_name'

  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta  AS last_name
         ON $wpdb->posts.ID = last_name.post_id AND last_name.meta_key='last_name'

      WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
      AND wp_posts.post_type = 'bo_codes'
        ";

$data = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );
```

I’ve spent many hours trying to wrap my head around this but I’m just not there yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out.

```
$query = "
            SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, cu.meta_value as customer, bc.meta_value as the_bo_code, st.meta_value as status, au.meta_value as author, rn.meta_value as run_number                
            FROM $wpdb->posts
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS cu ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = cu.post_id AND cu.meta_key='author')
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS bc ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = bc.post_id AND bc.meta_key='the_bo_code')                
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS st ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = st.post_id AND st.meta_key='status')
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS au ON (cu.meta_value = au.user_id AND au.meta_key='nickname')
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS rn ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = rn.post_id AND rn.meta_key='run_number')
            WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'bo_code_run'
            AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
            GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 50;
        ";
$data = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );
```